# The file "Twig.xml" does not exist

Tags: symfony, filter, twig, xml-twig

I'm following the symfony2 tutorial and was trying to create the Twig filter extension in chapter 5 http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/customising-the-view-more-with-twig.html however, I'm not sure what I've done but when I load the page now I get the following error:

> InvalidArgumentException: The file "Twig.xml" does not exist (in: /var/www/tester/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config).

Any idea why twig.xml doesn't exist and how I can re-create it?

I started by adding `{{ comment.created|created_ago }}` to my sidebar.html.twig file. I then created a 'Twig' folder within /src/tester/TestBundle/ and then an 'Extensions' folder within this. Then I created /testerTestBundleExtension.php within 'Extensions' with the following code:

```
namespace tester\TestBundle\Twig\Extensions;

class testerTestExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            'created_ago' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'createdAgo'),
        );
    }

    public function createdAgo(\DateTime $dateTime)
    {
        $delta = time() - $dateTime->getTimestamp();
        if ($delta < 0)
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("createdAgo is unable to handle dates in the future");

        $duration = "";
        if ($delta < 60)
        {
            // Seconds
            $time = $delta;
            $duration = $time . " second" . (($time > 1) ? "s" : "") . " ago";
        }
        else if ($delta <= 3600)
        {
            // Mins
            $time = floor($delta / 60);
            $duration = $time . " minute" . (($time > 1) ? "s" : "") . " ago";
        }
        else if ($delta <= 86400)
        {
            // Hours
            $time = floor($delta / 3600);
            $duration = $time . " hour" . (($time > 1) ? "s" : "") . " ago";
        }
        else
        {
            // Days
            $time = floor($delta / 86400);
            $duration = $time . " day" . (($time > 1) ? "s" : "") . " ago";
        }

        return $duration;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'tester_test_extension';
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I've now removed the vendors directory and re-ran `php composer.phar install' and now Im getting the following error:

> ServiceNotFoundException: The service "twig" has a dependency on a non-existent service "assetic.twig_extension".

Also, is my app/autoload.php correct?

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

// intl
if (!function_exists('intl_get_error_code')) {
    require_once      __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs/functions.php';

    $loader->add('', __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs');
}

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

return $loader;
```

**UPDATE:**

My composer.json is below:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "twig/twig": "1.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "doctrine/data-fixtures": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "symlink"
    } }
```

Comment: please post some code. Maybe there is a typo or sth.

Comment: Which version of Sf are you using? IIRC that tutorial is for Sf2.0, and there have been a number of BC-breaking changes in 2.1.

Comment: @taveo - code added to original post.

Comment: Run `php composer.phar update` and please give us your composer.json

Comment: When I run php composer.phar update I get the following:

    The service "twig" has a dependency on a non-existent service "assetic.twig_extension".

Comment: I've added my composer.json file in the original question

Answer (score 1):

If you create Twig Extension in symfony, you have mark it as a service

For example in tester/TestBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

```
services:
  test_bundle.twig.tester_test_extension:
    class: tester\TestBundle\Twig\Extensions\testerTestExtension
    tags:
      - { name: twig.extension }
```

For more info check documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: Thanks. I've marked it as a service now using your example above, however still getting the error. Do I need to re-install the twig extension?

Comment: Also, if I try and clear my cache I get the error - [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                                                                
  The file "Twig.xml" does not exist (in: /var/www/tester/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config).

Answer (score 1):

Your composer.json appears to be incorrect.  Rather than

```
"twig/twig": "1.*",
```

that line should be:

```
"twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
```